# Simplify Expressions with Racket

Tags: scheme, expression, racket, simplify

I have a function that differentiates an equation and prints it as a list to the screen. What I want to make now is a function that takes the expression returned like this one:
'(+ (* x 0) (* 2 1))
and simplifies the answer. Gets rid of x*0 since that always evaluates to zero and replaces 2*1 with 2, ultimately returning only 2 since 2 + 0 is 2.
This is what I have so far and obviously it is sorely lacking, any help on getting this started will be greatly appreciated.

```
(define (simplify expr)
  (if (not (list? expr))
      expr
      (if (null? (cdr expr)) 
          (car expr)
          (case (car expr)
           ((+
               ))

       ))
```

Answer (score 3):

The general solution for this kind of problem is not *that* simple. To get you started, think about using rewrite rules, take a look at the `simplify` procedure shown in section 4 of the article [A Hacker's Introduction to Partial Evaluation](http://wry.me/misc/peval.html):

```
We can use rewrite rules to simplify algebraic expressions. For example,

> (simplify '(+ (* 3 x) (* x 3)))
; (* 6 x)

This works by applying a list of rules to all parts of the subject expression
repeatedly until no more simplifications are possible:

(define *simplification-rules*
  '(((+ ?x ?x)          (* 2 ?x))
    ((* ?s ?n)          (* ?n ?s))
    ((* ?n (* ?m ?x))   (* (* ?n ?m) ?x))
    ((* ?x (* ?n ?y))   (* ?n (* ?x ?y)))
    ((* (* ?n ?x) ?y)   (* ?n (* ?x ?y)))))

The left hand column has patterns to match, while the right hand holds responses. 
The first rule says, if you see (+ foo foo), rewrite it into (* 2 foo). Variables 
like ?x can match anything, while ?m and ?n can only match numbers.
```

Comment: It depends on the context. I quoted verbatim from the source, sometimes they use `?s`, `?n`, etc. as the variable name, instead of `?x`

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you just have binary expressions with '* and '+ as operators, it is easy enough to encode the basic rules of algebra with a recursive descent of the expression to be simplified.  As so:

```
(define (simplify exp)
 (cond ((number? exp) exp)
       ((symbol? exp) exp)
       ((list?   exp)
        (assert (= 3 (length exp)))
        (let ((operator  (list-ref exp 0))
              (operand-1 (simplify (list-ref exp 1)))   ; recurse
              (operand-2 (simplify (list-ref exp 2))))  ; recurse
          (case operator
            ((+)
             (cond ((and (number? operand-1) (= 0 operand-1)) operand-2)
                   ((and (number? operand-2) (= 0 operand-2)) operand-1)
                   ((and (number? operand-1) (number? operand-2)) 
                    (+ operand-1 operand-2))
                   (else `(,operator ,operand-1 ,operand-2))))

            ((*)
             (cond ((and (number? operand-1) (= 0 operand-1)) 0)
                   ((and (number? operand-2) (= 0 operand-2)) 0)
                   ((and (number? operand-1) (= 1 operand-1)) operand-2)
                   ((and (number? operand-2) (= 1 operand-2)) operand-1)
                   ((and (number? operand-1) (number? operand-2)) 
                    (* operand-1 operand-2))
                   (else `(,operator ,operand-1 ,operand-2))))
            (else 'unknown-operator))))
       (else 'unknown-expression)))
```

This only performs one pass over the expression.  Generally you'd want to perform passes until the result doesn't change.